# Unable to find the location of error

Tags: linux, spring-mvc, logback

My server logs are full with following error messages
No clue where to find this issue, I have Spring based MVC Controllers. I checked every where but not able to find. (Tomcat 8, AWS Linux)

```
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:77)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:47)
        at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:603)
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
        at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:113)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:423)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:107)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:64)
        ... 43 more
```

Comment: You are trying to convert the string into integer but the string is null. And you trying to convert the null value to integer, so getting the NumberFormatException

Comment: Check the input parameter comes in the controller from front end is correct or not. The value come from the front end is null on that controller and spring try to convert that null value in integer because the type of parameters defined at the controller is Integer. That's why you getting that exception

Comment: there are lots of api, is there some thing I enable and it tells which controller is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I am giving the way by which you log the error and exception to best extent and this help you debug the error easily.

**1. Log the request url(controller url) and request parameter -**
      Log the request url with its parameter before it assign to controller.Means Log it before it go to controller handler method. (This helpfull in your case.Because spring throw exception before it handle by handler when try to convert the request parameter corresponding to controller handler method parameter).By this you know what is parameter is recive for which controller url

**2.Log the request url and response parameter** Again log the request url with its response parameter. This helpfull in identify what response is send for this url

**3. Log the exception with request url** - If you are generating own custom exception like CustomException. Then make a field in CustomException class which take the url,so when you log it , you easily identity for which url this exception is created. For other exception and error, try to make the common exception handler class, and make the method in this class which is called in catch block which catch Throwable and Log the print stack trace in that method

Below are sample code :-

```
   public CustomException extends Exception{
    String requestUrl;
    String message;
    }
```

Common Handler method

```
     public static handleException(Throwable throwable, url){
      //Log print stack trace


      }
```

For the spring you can use ExceptionHandler, you can easily find about that by googling

For the 1st and 2nd point in spring you can use the HandlerInterceptorAdapter, please learn about that.

Below showing the example code

```
public class LogInteceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
    .getLogger(LogInteceptor.class);


//This method called before controller method handle the request
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {


//Log other things also 

//Logging the request url
logger.info("Request URL {} request param is {}" +  request.getRequestURL().toString(), request);
//if returned false, we need to make sure 'response' is sent
return true;
}

//This called before the model view send to view page for render
@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    //we can add attributes in the modelAndView and use that in the view page
}

//This called when response is going to sent
@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
        throws Exception {

}

 }
```